# Constructing a new configurable class

Tags: typescript

I am trying to create configurable classes that can have default value but if required its configuration can be changed.

The idea is that class should be instanciated by calling its type specified in static properties of Test class.

```
// Example
const app = Test.App // should return new instance of App class
```

also, we should configure it if required

```
// Example
const configured = Test.App.configure({...configuration}) // Should return new instance
```

Main issue is that App constructor is called only once regardless of how many times I call the Test.App - it simply creates a singleton :(

if required
class App {
public config: any;

```
  constructor(a: string) {
    console.log(this);
  }

  public configure(conf: any) {
    this.config = conf;
    return this;
  }
}

class Test {
  public static App = new App('App');
}

class Eval {
  constructor() {
    const a = Test.App.configure({test: true});
    const b = Test.App;

    console.log('Test', a, b);
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use a getter to create a new object on each call

```
class Test {
  public static get App() {return new App('App')};
}
```

If you call `Test.App` twice it'll be 2 different objects, but there is no way to predict if `Test.App` is called by itself of a `configure` call will follow